# Issue using whenever gem

Tags: ruby, cron, rake, whenever

I am trying to use `whenever` gem in my application but I am not able to run rake command in `schedule.rb`.

Error which is throwing up is

```
/bin/bash: rake: command not found
```

I am also using bundler so all my gems are freezed into the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is rake in somewhere atypical, like /usr/local/bin? Try adding this to schedule.rb:

```
env :PATH, '/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'command' instead of rake.  My rake is in /usr/local/bin and I can't figure out how to make it work either.  So here's an example of a command instead in schedule.rb:

```
every 5.minutes do
  command "cd " + `pwd`.chomp + " && RAILS_ENV=#{environment} /usr/local/bin/rake rakefile:rakemethod"
end
```

Note you also have to pass in environment in this example.  I think you just do it with 'whenever --update_crontab --set environment=beta' when you call schedule.rb.

I have capistrano do it using the capistrano recipes in the whenever gem (see lib dirs under the whenever source).  I do have to set whenever_environment in my capistrano deploy script.

whenever could default to production so I'd just play around with it and see.  In other words, you may not need the RAILS_ENV=#{environment} if you are only doing this in production.  I have several staging environments so I pass in the environment to help out the script.

If only I could specify a different rake directory to get this to work with /usr/local/bin/rake!  Anyone help on that front?